# How to make an index optional?

Tags: options, optional-arguments

Can I define a relation between variables, such that the expression will also be evaluated (then assuming all indices are equal) when no index is given?
$$ x_i + y_j = \delta_{ij} \stackrel{Mathematica\ recognizes \ then\ that}{\Rightarrow} x + y = \delta_{ii} = 1 $$
$$$$ 
$$$$

*INITIAL QUESTION WAS:*
I define a relation for the annihilation and creation operator $a_i$ and $a_j$ like this
$$[a_i, a_j^\dagger] = \delta_{ij}.$$

The commutator can be defined with the [Quantum Notation package](http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/lgomez/quantum/). I want to make the index ($i$, resp. $j$) **optional**, such that Mathematica recognizes that
$$[a, a^\dagger] =1,$$
i.e. it assumes $i=j$ if no index is given. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: how do you currently define the relation? (for existing indices)

Comment: showing us your code could make things easier

Comment: Dear Wizard, Dear Pinguin Dirk, I actually define the relation exactly like this $$[a_i, a_j^\dagger] = KroneckerDelta[ij],$$ since the Quantum Notation package supports commutator notation. I just asked out of curiosity, in the moment I am using the "double definition" (one time with and one time without indices) as swish suggested.

Answer (score -1):

I have this package installed, so that's what I did, and everything worked:

[image]

Comment: Could you please 1) provide a link to the Quantum notation package and 2) edit in the real copyable code instead of the image?